# chrome extension memory not freed when page is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote an extension with a background page bg.html and another UI page ui.html. When the extension was first loaded, I saw in the Task Manager that it used about **20mb** memory. Then I opened the UI page, the memory went up to **170mb**(the UI is quite complicated, I may ask a separate question for that). When I closed the UI page, memory was not totally freed(**160mb remaining**). I am aware that Chrome may not decide to perform GC right after I close the page, but it seems that it actually never free that memory(after a long period of time), and when I open the page again and again, it will consume more and more memory.

Is this a normal behavior? Or is it caused by some memory leaks in my code? Such great memory consumption can be quite frightening to users.

By the way, I took heap snapshot in dev tools, bg.html used 5.3mb, and ui.html 7.5mb

Comment: Might be related to this [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=441500)

Comment: Have you tried to use [`persistent:false`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) for the background page? The chromium bug that @abraham stated didn't clearly mentioned this as a solution but might be worth a try as a short term solution.

Comment: Thanks, the bug seems to be related. My extension uses a lot of other apis, which are not compatible with persistent: false. Currently I don't plan to switch to Event pages, I am not sure if I can do that without loss of functionality and also that will lead to a huge change to my code structure.

Comment: FYI, looks like the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=441500) mentioned was recently fixed, so you should give this antother try with the chrome dev or canary channel and see if it solves the problem for your extension